# Не компилируется файл с названием пакета не main

Tags: golang, пакет

```
package s
import "fmt"
func main(){
    fmt.Println("s")
}
```

Если компилировать командой `go build s.go`, то ошибок не выдаст, но так же нет и самого исполняемого файла. А если пакет назвать `main` вместо `s`, то все прекрасно компилируется.
Создавал и папку `GoPath` и прописал переменной `GOPATH` путь до нее, и поддиректории `src`,`pkg`,`bin` делал. Вообщем не понимаю я как компилировать не `main` пакеты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А где вы ищете скомпилированный пакет? Если ошибок нет, то файл должен быть. Добавьте флаг `-o`:

```
go build -o /path/s.a s.go
```

И в папке `/path/` ищите ваш пакет `s.a`.
Можно еще проще сделать, командой `install`. Тогда указывать путь не нужно, все будет лежать в `%GOPATH%/pkg`.

С другой стороны, зачем вам в пакете "не main" функция `main()`? `package s` подразумевает, что вы создаете некую библиотеку `s`, это не исполняемый файл. И компилировать его нужно лишь в том случае, если вы его хотите распространять в скомпилированном виде.

Если вы все-таки хотите исполняемый файл, то называйте ваш пакет `main`